# Can't detect T::value() using auto to parametrize true_type

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, template-meta-programming, sfinae

Using SFINAE, `has_value_int<T>` and `has_value_auto<T>` both try to detect whether class `T` has a `static constexpr` function named `value`.

- Using `int` to parametrize `true_type`, `has_value_int<T>` works for
  demo classes `pass` and `fail`.
- Using `auto` to parameterize `true_type`, `has_value_auto<T>` always returns false.

What's the difference between using `int` and using `auto`, and why does `auto` not work?

Specifically, why does overload resolution prefer `match_auto(...)` to `match_auto(int)`?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// parametrize true_type 
template <int> using true_int = true_type; // works
template <auto> using true_auto = true_type; // does not work

// detect if T::value() is a valid compile-time expression
template <class T> true_int<(T::value(), void(), 0)> match_int(int);
template <class T> true_auto<(T::value(), void(), 0)> match_auto(int);
template <class> false_type match_int(...); // sometimes called
template <class> false_type match_auto(...); // always called
template <class T>
static constexpr bool has_value_int = decltype(match_int<T>(0))::value;
template <class T>
static constexpr bool has_value_auto = decltype(match_auto<T>(0))::value;

template <class T>
void demo() {
    cout << has_value_int<T> << "(int), " // sometimes false
            << has_value_auto<T> << "(auto)" << endl; // always false
}

int main() {
    struct pass { static constexpr int value() { return 1; } };
    using fail = float;

    cout << "has_value<pass> = "; demo<pass>(); // 1(int), 0(auto)
    cout << "has_value<fail> = "; demo<fail>(); // 0(int), 0(auto)

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: [Compiled using gcc 7.3.0](https://wandbox.org/permlink/czFLNMp1LmTGfpYK).
Same with [clang works](https://wandbox.org/permlink/bfgZCn0QnHfVi7L8).

Comment: I smell a gcc bug :)

Comment: I wonder if `auto` is less specific than `(...)`.

Comment: Works with clang and VC++ (/std:c++17)

Comment: Submitted [86703](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=86703).

Comment: Unrelated, it's not "ADL" preferring one to the other... it's overload resolution. ADL doesn't play a role here.

Comment: @Barry: Thanks, I've edited my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference; this is a gcc bug, reported by Barry as [#86703](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=86703).

As a workaround, don't use functions:

```
// detect if T::value() is a valid compile-time expression
template <typename T, typename = void> struct match_auto : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct match_auto<T, std::void_t<true_auto<(T::value(), void(), 0)>>>
    : std::true_type {};

template <class T> static constexpr bool has_value_auto = match_auto<T>::value;
```